# Some problem in calculating the meyer wavelet using IFFT

Tags: python, numpy, fft, wavelet

I'm newbie in python and numpy. I have to calculate the meyer wavelet in time domain using spectral analysis. Due to https://academic.oup.com/gji/article/116/1/119/635254  the wavelet can be estimated in frequency domain by
[image]

I have tried to write a code in python to construct this wavelet in time domain

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 1024
fs = 50
df = fs / N
f = np.arange(-N / 2, N / 2) * df
w = 2 * np.pi * f


def hw(w):
    h = []
    for i in np.arange(len(w)):
        if w[i] > 0:
            h.append(np.exp(-1 / w[i] / w[i]))
        else:
            h.append(0)
    return np.array(h)


def gw(w):
    return hw(4 * np.pi / 3 - w) / (hw(w - 2 * np.pi / 3) + hw(4 * np.pi / 3 - w))


def phiw(w):
    return np.sqrt(gw(w) * gw(-w))


def syw(w):
    return np.exp(-1j * w / 2) * np.sqrt(phiw(w / 2) * phiw(w / 2) - phiw(w) * phiw(w))


s = syw(w)
st = np.fft.ifft(np.fft.ifftshift(s))
st = np.fft.fftshift(np.real(st))
t = np.arange(-N / 2, N / 2) / fs

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(t, st)
plt.xlim([-10, 10])
plt.show()
```

but I got wrong amplitude in time domain!!??

[image]

[image]

ps: The domain and amplitude can't be retrived through this code. Any suggestion is welcome

[image: The figure in the article]

Comment: what is the expected amplitude of the wavelet in the time domain then?

Comment: @Yacola: It should be around 8 as it was shown in the manuscript. May be I forget a normalization factor?

Comment: I suspect you have missed one normalization factor related to the ifft definition, namely `N/2`, and I am quite confident about this one, but more importantly, you may have missed one related to the wavelet definition itself, but it is more of a guess here...

Comment: @Yacola: the definition is quit correct due to several references but I did not find any N/2 normalization any where? could you guide me

Comment: The default normalization of `np.fft` has the direct transforms unscaled and the inverse transforms are scaled by `1/N` from the numpy documentation. So you should unscale it by multiplying by `N` (`N/2` was coming from a different script of mine...), but since real and imaginary parts, and amplitude are the same as in the manuscript, I think you are close. On a very different aspect you could just simplify `hw(w)` function with the one-liner `np.where(w > 0, np.exp(-1 / w**2), 0)`

Comment: @Yacola: Thank you for your kind help and guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

st = np.fft.fftshift(np.real(st))

with

st = np.fft.fftshift(np.real(st)) * fs

and you will get the correct scaling, I believe.

Dr. Saturn